# Robolectric using Fragments and ActionBarCompat NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, robolectric

I have an android application which uses fragments and has implemented ActionBarCompat. I wrote simple Robolectric test shown below:

```
@Test
public void shouldNotBeNull() throws Exception {
    MainFragment mainFragment = new MainFragment();
    startFragment(mainFragment);
    assertThat(mainFragment, notNullValue());
    assertThat(mainFragment.getActivity(), notNullValue());
}

private void startFragment(MainFragment fragment) {
    FragmentActivity activity = new FragmentActivity();
    shadowOf(activity).callOnCreate(null);
    shadowOf(activity).callOnStart();
    shadowOf(activity).callOnResume();

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(fragment, null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

I am getting following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at android.app.Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu(Activity.java:2595)
at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatHoneycomb.invalidateOptionsMenu(ActivityCompatHoneycomb.java:30)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(FragmentActivity.java:572)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setHasOptionsMenu(Fragment.java:708)
at com.example.android.ui.MainFragment.onCreate(MainFragment.java:599)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:834)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1080)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1416)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:420)
at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.postDelayed(Scheduler.java:37)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.post(ShadowLooper.java:198)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowHandler.postDelayed(ShadowHandler.java:56)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowHandler.post(ShadowHandler.java:51)
at android.os.Handler.post(Handler.java)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1322)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:541)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:525)
at com.example.android.ui.MainFragmentTest.startFragment(MainFragmentTest.java:36)
at com.example.android.ui.MainFragmentTest.shouldNotBeNull(MainFragmentTest.java:22)
```

When using something like this:

```
MainActivity activity = new MainActivity();
shadowOf(activity).callOnCreate(null);
shadowOf(activity).callOnStart();
shadowOf(activity).callOnResume();
```

where MainActivity is holder activity for MainFragment, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.robolectric.res.builder.RobolectricPackageManager.getActivityInfo(RobolectricPackageManager.java:59)
at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.getUiOptionsFromMetadata(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:157)
at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:53)
at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
at com.example.android.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowActivity.invokeReflectively(ShadowActivity.java:176)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowActivity.callOnCreate(ShadowActivity.java:121)
at com.example.android.ui.MainFragmentTest.startFragment(MainFragmentTest.java:28)
at com.example.android.ui.MainFragmentTest.shouldNotBeNull(MainFragmentTest.java:22)
```

I suspect it could be something about ActionBarCompat and Robolectric not being compatible. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does `shadowOf(activity)` return?

Comment: Thanks for participating. As for explanation of shadowOf method, best one is given on robolectric web site: "Sometimes Android classes don’t provide methods to access the state of the Android objects under test. The Robolectric.shadowOf() methods provide reference to the shadow instances representing Android objects, allowing tests to assert on state otherwise not available". If otherwise you assumed that shadowOf(activity) returns null while debugging, id doesn't.

Comment: The problem btw still persists, so any suggestion would be helpfull.

Comment: No, I was wondering what was the return type to see on which object the `callOnCreate(null)` method is executed - maybe callOnCreate with null doesn't work?

Comment: The return type is ShadowActivity which is fine. The object is not null. As for passing null on callOnCreate, that is also fine, it only means that there isn't any saved bundle to pass to activity. Anyway, the idea for my testing logic can be viewed here [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568128/java-lang-illegalstateexception-activity-has-been-destroyed)

Comment: Hey, have you been able to make any progress on this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't found solution for this problem.

Comment: Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12903280/1000837

Comment: Have you tried to put @Config(reportsdk=10) annoation?

Answer (score 0):

As of Robolectric 2.4, it is supposed to support the Appcompat library. There are a few gotchas though as it doesn't work out of the box. Things that helped me:

1. Creating a `project.properties` file with the following contents

As described in [the config manual](http://robolectric.org/configuring/):

```
target=android-19 android.library.reference.1=/../../build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/20.0.0    
android.library.reference.2=/../../build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/support-v4/20.0.0
android.library.reference.3=/../../build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.viewpagerindicator/library/2.4.1
```

2. Setting exculdes in `build.gradle` for Robolectric

Apparently Robolectric has its own versions of the support libraries so the following is needed to prevent possible duplicate dependencies (referenced from [here](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1175)):

```
   androidTestCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4') {
    exclude module: 'classworlds'
    exclude module: 'commons-logging'
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
    exclude module: 'maven-artifact'
    exclude module: 'maven-artifact-manager'
    exclude module: 'maven-error-diagnostics'
    exclude module: 'maven-model'
    exclude module: 'maven-project'
    exclude module: 'maven-settings'
    exclude module: 'plexus-container-default'
    exclude module: 'plexus-interpolation'
    exclude module: 'plexus-utils'
    exclude module: 'wagon-file'
    exclude module: 'wagon-http-lightweight'
    exclude module: 'wagon-provider-api'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7' }
```